# What is the best manner to find and plot boundaries in an array?

Tags: python, data-visualization

I apologize if this question is too vague, but as someone without a coding background, I'm having a difficult time articulating my problem.

I have two 2D arrays that look like

```
[[1.509, 2.321,..., nan,nan,],
 [1.401, 3.744,...,nan, nan,],
...,
[ nan, nan, ..., nan, nan]]
```

One of these arrays I am using to determine the Z axis on a 3D plot (included). I'm hoping for a way to collect the last float before where the nan's start and just plot that line as a boundary.

I can get a boolean array from `np.isnan(array_a)`, but I don't know how to find the points that border `True / False`. This boundary is sketched red on my attached image.

The same sort of question applies, but I have an array that colors the points I am plotting. I can search `np.where(array_b > 1.0)`, which returns array indices, but I want to find the boundary where there are values included in there versus not. The boundary for this is sketched blue on my attached image.

Does anyone have a suggestion about what would be the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from your problem, you are looking to find the index of the first occurrence of a nan in a 2D NumPy array.

```
boundary_points = []
for i in range(len(arr)):
     boundary_points.append([i,arr[i].index(np.nan)])
```

You can also try

```
np.array([(s, list(row).index(np.nan)) for s,row in enumerate(arr) if np.nan in row])
```

This will also take care of rows where there are no nan values. :)

Comment: Is there a nice vectorized way to do this? Especially for a 2D array

Comment: np.array([(s, list(row).index(np.nan)) for s,row in enumerate(arr) if np.nan in row])